# Endpoint not accessible after Boot 2.6 upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

After upgrading the Boot version in my project to `2.6.0`, my endpoint is no longer accessible, I'm automatically redirected to the login page even though I configured it with a `permitAll()` directive:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("presentations")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is actually related to how Spring Boot processes the `mvcMatchers` values after the upgrade:

> The default strategy for matching request paths against registered Spring MVC handler mappings has changed from AntPathMatcher to PathPatternParser.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#deferred-openid-connect-discovery

And this new setup requires my `presentations` pattern to start with `/`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .mvcMatchers("/presentations")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
}
```

Alternatively, if I had several routes and I need a quick fix I could set up the following application property to revert this to its previous behavior:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

BTW, `path-pattern-parser` is the default value, as it seems to be more efficient... here is some additional information on this and on the differences between `PathPatternParser` and `AntPathMatcher`:

- https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.13/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

EDIT: I also realized that using `antMatchers()` made some of my `MockMvc` tests fail, this was a bug that got fixed in Boot `2.6.1`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after migrating to 2.6.2 but in my case I'm using .antMatchers(), that shouldn't have changed, right?